# How to set macro condition for day of today in any of list

Tags: sql, date, sas, sas-macro

I wanna set the code run at days: 5,11,16,22,28 monthly but it doesn't work.

```
%if %sysfunc(day(%sysfunc(today()))) in (5,11,16,22,28) %then %do
```

How can I fix it? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IN` operator works in a SAS 9.2 Macro but you need to define system options. The `MINOPERATOR` (Macro-In-Operator) must be turned on and in your case, the `MINDELILITER` too must be specified as you are using comma delimited values.
More information can be found in [Getting the IN operator to FUNCTION inside a SAS® Macro](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug09/cc/CC05.pdf)

```
options minoperator mindelimiter=',';
%if %sysfunc(day(%sysfunc(today())-1)) in (5,11,16,22,28) %then %do;
    %put do smth...;
%end; 

do smth...
```

Notice the `-1` in the above example to replicate March 22.

Comment: Thanks Kermit much, I tried but still not work. honestly, I'm using SAS 7.1. Do you know any solution for this version?

Comment: 71 must be the version of something else, like Enterprise Guide or SAS/Studio.  You cannot be using SAS 7.1, they never made a SAS 7.1.  There was a short lived SAS 7 but really the next version after SAS 6 was SAS 8.  The current version of SAS is 9.4 which has had many maintenance releases.

Comment: Yes, it's SAS Enterprise Guide version 7.13. :(

Comment: Enterprise Guide is just the GUI tool you are using to submit the SAS code. Knowing that does not help. What is the version of SAS that is running the SAS code?  Check the value of the automatic macro variable SYSVLONG.

Comment: I see it. it's v9.04. But I don't know why it still doesn't work. Any way I can share you my screen?

Comment: I am running on `9.04.01M6P110718` and it is working.

Comment: Great news it worked. I restarted my PC and refer to your suggestion. Thank you so muchhhh.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider accepting the answer if you think this solves the problem.